# What is a beginner-friendly microcontroller and why?

Tags: microcontroller

I can do basic electronics.  I want to experiment with microcontrollers but the world is awash in a myriad of choices.  This is paralyzing.

What are beginner-friendly choices and why?  Bonus love for information about extra equipment needed (like a chip programmer), dev kits, or DIP-friendly packaging.

This is mostly about learning. If I were going to do a project, it would be to configure switches and other sensors in the chicken coops to monitor door status and temperature etc, and then send a status report back to a receiving station at the house via a laser (?).  Something like that.

EDIT - I am a programmer by trade, though I have never done any embedded programming. I am experienced in assembler coding as well as c coding. Doing a thing on an event or when a pin goes high doesn't sound challenging. I could be showing my ignorance :-D

Comment: ... just buy an Arduino to get your feet wet, there's nothing easier to get started with. There are countless examples to learn from on the internet.

Comment: Added information about my programming background. Does Arduino remain a good learning vehicle or is too much work done for me?

Comment: I mean if you _want_ it to be hard there are no shortage of ways to achieve that... there's more to embedded than programming though,  and Arduino is great for prototyping and learning without getting in the weeds of setting up a dev toolchain since bootloader is included and integrated with the IDE. Otherwise it's just C++ after all. Personally I would get an ESP32 dev board so you get BLE and Wi-Fi capability and lots of memory to play with too. Look up Heltec ESP32 LoRa and you get a little OLED display and LoRaWAN capability as a bonus.

Comment: Choose the one what has the biggest community around. For self-learning is hard to understand just from datasheets, appnotes... Sometimes you freez at point you will need some help and most straightforward way is to find sulution on internet or ask on forum. Once you reach some level you can choose a micro whatever you want and work with it almost immediatelly.

Comment: There used to be two good choices - PIC or AVR. Then Microchip developed MPLAB X and bought out Atmel. Now there are none :(.

Comment: If you think there's too much work done for you already with an Arduine, start with the core of the platform: the ATmega 328P. It has plenty of features and a datasheet a couple hundred pages thick.

Comment: Surely there's a middle ground @Mast

Comment: The 328P is fairly complete for a beginner. You won't need all the functions it has, but it's a fairly good start to begin with. Either you want something very simple or you don't, what's it you're looking for specifically?

Comment: I want to learn without excessive agony. I don't even know what a microprocessor really is, tbh. Sounds like a computer-on-a-chip but I suspect there's more to it.

Answer (score 4):

- The micro should have the peripherals you need.

For example if you need WiFi or whatever, that will narrow down your choices. ESP32 is a nice micro, btw, a bit power hungry, but cheap and powerful. Besides the WiFi, its most notable perk is the multichannel PWM with dithering which is great for LEDs.

- Cheap development board or module so you can hack it and not care if you fry it, with lots of IO available on pin headers, and USB connectivity for programming.

No separate programmer should be necessary to get started. It is also quite useful if the board can double as a programmer and work with the micro itself if you use it on a PCB of your own design. All modern micros support in-circuit programming, so there is no need to use a socket, pull the micro, put it in a programmer, etc. For example, an arduino can act as an AVR programmer, STM32 Nucleo board can also act as a programmer by moving some jumpers on it so these can program a chip on your board. The manufacturers want to sell micros, so they want students to play with their cheap boards so when they graduate and get a job they will use their products in their designs.

- Functioning build tools with fast compile-upload

For example I'm working on a STM32G0. It takes about one second to compile the application, flash it in the micro, and execute it. This is convenient. Some toolchains are much slower, which is a pain.

- If there is an IDE, it should be usable.

For example, arduino IDE is garbage, but fortunately it can be replaced with a makefile and a text editor, so no problem. But arduino does not offer debugging, this requires a debug probe or other contortions. More modern micros offer debugging via the USB chip on the eval board. For example, with most ARM chips from ST or NXP, the IDE is Eclipse which sucks, but the debugger is really nice. Basically, hit "Debug" and one second later it is compiled and flashed and you can single step the code, set breakpoints, etc. This is really convenient. It feels like developing on a PC. The ST interface is quite fast so there is no noticeable lag. The NXP hardware I used a few years ago was a lot more temperamental and laggy while debugging, maybe they fixed it.

- Lots of online documentation and tutorials

If you want to go bare metal, a proper datasheet helps. But if you want to use the libraries and code provided by the manufacturer, then it helps to use a micro that a lot of other people use, so you can find online examples. So, pick a popular micro, there is arduino of course, STM32, ESP32, etc.

The AVR micro on the arduino is pretty simple, but more modern ARM chips are quite complex with tons of peripherals. So documentation is really important, and also pin configuration. For example ESP32 gives you easy to use functions to assign pins to peripherals and decide what goes where. ST makes a GUI tool so you can click on stuff and assign functions to pins, then it generates the initialization code for you. In both cases reading the docs is not optional if you want to know what the peripheral actually does.

Arduino holds your hand a lot, which is nice, you can get stuff done fast. If you need to interface with a chip, say an I2C chip or a sensor, someone wrote a library for it, that saves time. Arduino is a bit like lego. You copypaste random stuff from the internet, and usually it works. The drawback is that the code quality of many of these libraries is pretty bad.

STM32 holds your hand a bit, but the learning curve is steeper, so you have to read the manual. Also the micro has lots more stuff. For example you can program it to fire a set of ADC channels on a timer, have DMA copy the results to RAM in a rolling buffer, and raise an interrupt when the buffer is half-full. That's a bit of setup. But the reason it's more complicated than on an AVR micro is mostly because the AVR micro can't do any of that.

ESP32 is somewhat in the middle.

Answer (score 4):

As @vicactu suggests, Arduino would be a good starting point. Why?

Let's assume you start with a bare microcontroller chip -
To get it to run, you would need to read and understand the datasheet then formulate a circuit and be able to verify the operation. To do this correctly you'd need to have an electronic engineering degree or similar learning to give you the base knowledge to understand the datasheet. There's plenty of bad examples on the interwebs where people throw something together and it 'works'. You'll also find people here and elsewhere on the interwebs where they've tried throwing something together and it doesn't work.

Then you have to understand enough about the chip and then learn a programming language along with the compiler and other tools to get a led flashing.

At some point you'd have to draw the line and concentrate on a specific skill you want to learn. Eg - the drive a car, do you REALLY need to fully understand how the engine works?

This is where the likes of Arduino come in. You can purchase a piece of hardware that has been adequately designed that will work 'out of the box'. The idea is that you get the board, plug it into your computer and with one keypress, code can be loaded and run. Next are the software tools that you load and again, they just work 'out of the box'. Then there are the code libraries that do the things that you are most likely to need.

This gives you a solid base that you can work from. Sure, most of the difficult and tricky stuff has been done for you so you can concentrate on learning programming and hardware skills where you have a chance of success. In ten minutes you can have a led flashing. From that you can build your skills.

Frequently you'll hear comments like 'Arduino is for kids' or 'it's too restrictive' etc. Sure, you can give an Arduino board to a school kid, point them towards a website that tells them step by step how to wire a led and make it flash. That's always a good starting point. As for 'too restrictive' or inefficient etc, you get to choose if you use the Arduino libraries or not. Some of them are not particularly efficient - there's a price to be paid for ease of use, besides, if you're flashing leds or turning relays on or off, what's a few microseconds here or there?

The Arduino tools come under some criticism. The Arduino editor sucks - it's cheap 'n' cheerful but it does what it needs to. There's other options like platformio if you want more full featured, but there's a step up in the base knowledge you need. Under the covers is the same gcc compiler that a person skilled in the art would probably use anyways.

More importantly, is the Arduino ecosystem - a standardised method of managing libraries and plenty of examples of how to do anything half useful. If there's not an Arduino library for what chip you want to use or an example, then you have really ventured off the freeway. There's plenty of garbage libraries and suspect tutorials, but there's also some very high quality ones. That's a small price to pay vs doing everything from scratch.

My day job is embedded systems, so when I'm choosing a microcontroller for a project is to determine if there is an eval board with Arduino support. That means I have a hardware platform that works and a software framework to get me started. From that I can design my custom hardware and pcb. If something doesn't work, I can always refer to the eval board. I might not even use the Arduino tools for the production code, but I have the Arduino code to reference if I have a problem.

At some point you ask yourself 'how many i2c or uart drivers do I need to write in my lifetime'? As well, the average IoT project might have a webserver, tcpip stack, usb, filesystem etc. To write all of that code from scratch is many man years of effort.

One other way of answering the question of whether to Arduino or not is the cost of entry is low. A board might be, say, USD $10. In the western world that might get you a MacDonald's meal. It might just be the best $10 you ever spent.

Comment: seems Bob & I were writing much the same stuff in parallel! Two opinions from two different people separated by 1000's of miles!

Comment: Well, I'll have to offer another one then that is different. ;) (Not that I necessarily disagree. Just that I have different nuances I might call out.)

Comment: High-five!.. :D

Answer (score 2):

First off, it sounds like you have the important two programming skills for embedded work even if you aren't a self-proclaimed embedded programmer. C and assembly are vital and you've got them. So that means you are past one hurdle, already.

### Resonances

When I take on a project I first look at my own skills and the problems in front of me. I then try and formulate how I would solve those problems using tools I've used before or else have heard of and feel I could muster my way through, if needed. Stuff within grasp, so to speak. If I can work out a path that uses skills I have or can easily get and achieve a solution to the problem, then I sit down and start codifying a much more detailed plan. I keep pushing on that plan, squeezing out ever increasing levels of detail, until it's totally clear in mind.

While the above is going on I'm also looking at things like cost, weight, availability, power sources, environment and environmental seals, distance, etc. Even if during the above process I felt there were no project-killers, having the end-product of a fully detailed plan is a good time to *revisit* all that and review what's accumulated to see I'd missed any project-killers.

Then it's just a matter of deciding what pieces I need and in what order. Often, I have only a vague idea about some sensor (say, for example, a humidity sensor) because, although I may feel I understand what I've read about them, there is nothing like grabbing one or two of them and then running experiments to confirm my assumptions and beliefs about what I think I gathered from datasheets and reading about them. Papers may say one thing, my mind may read this as something else, and when I go to test out the sensor I find yet another thing I hadn't guessed about before. So this is the stage where I validate the assumptions and interpretations that went into the earlier work-product, one by one. It's important to separate them out into a prioritized sequence of validation tests because, if you wait until after creating the entire assembly before testing, you will have wasted a great amount of time and money if it turns out something you should have earlier caught isn't as you thought it was. So, test in bite-sized chunks and verify everything you can.

By this time, you almost don't have a problem. You've worked out a plan, followed through on the plan, and know a great deal about each section and that they work as expected. The rest is usually more a matter of getting the pieces assembled and your operating system design and software coding completed. But as you know so much by now, the design of the O/S and the software itself is much more perfuctory and determined by the data and processing rates -- which you understand pretty well by now.

So, you ask, *"What's a beginner friendly micro?" What you wrote about chicken coops helps narrow my thoughts a little. But not so much. Are we talking about fixed structures? Or are they mobile chicken-tractors? More than one structure? (Do you need multiple "channels" of information?) Are you going to be doing egg-hatching and need to monitor bath temperatures? I gather door-status matters. But are any of these details a matter where you need to run fast to take care of a situation? Or are all these things just "data collection" that will be post-processed at a convenient time?

### Someone you can call

The above is just the first resonances that ring in my bell-mind from your hammer-impact of an idea. But in considering what's better for you? I think you are better off securing something that others you know are using and where you can ask them questions. It usually turns out that the easiest micro to use is the micro where you have a friend you can call and about which you can then ask questions and get the answers you need on the spot. I don't think any other micro could compete with that. Even relatively complex micros are easy, if you have someone you can call and who will help you work through some struggle with it.

So. Who do you know that can help you through some development problem with a micro? If you know of anyone at all who will be there for you when you need it, then that's my answer to you. That micro and no other.

### Summary

Lacking that? Well, then it depends upon whether or not you feel you will be writing all of the software "stacks" or if you expect to use lots of existing library code. This goes back to what I wrote earlier, about laying out your own skillsets and matching those with the project problems to be solved.

But there are a few things to consider, too.

You mentioned a *receiving station* in the home. This is a completely different set of requirements and a different project. Many would just *use a PC.* But I didn't get that from your question. So you really have two different projects, here. A receiving station project and a remote sensor station project. And, frankly, a third project which is the bits that connect these up, which you also must define well. So that's really a third project, I think, and perhaps the more difficult one.

What are the distances involved? Do you have, or have access to, underground piping? (My pipes are designed to include "clean-outs" every so-and-so distance and I've made them large enough. I maintain a twine line inside, too, that I can use to pull new wires through.) Does this have to be wireless? If so, have you researched which bands and modules are legal over the distances involved? Can you use these technologies with simple code? Or do they require "protocol stacks" so complex that you do NOT want to write them, yourself? And again, do these support multiple communication channels, should you need them?

In short, I don't know. This is one of those "opinion questions" (or "too vague") that are often closed on this site. So I'll stop here. Besides, it's all the time I have. Best wishes!

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I know this is an opinion question. I almost didn't post it for that reason.  But look at the information in the answers. Surely this is worthy information.
I am assuming your questions are rhetorical, but in case they aren't, the coops are stationary. The barn is common to them all and is _probably_ out of wifi range.  I have power available. There are no conduits.  My PC might be the processor, but I ASSume I'll need a receiver.  I am alone in my nerdiness.

Comment: @TonyEnnis You are *not* alone. I have a 17'x42' chicken house with many dozens of chickens here. I've a small farm, 7 acres total but only a subset of it usable for growing food. I grow much of what we eat and buy from locals who also are growing different things during the year. Almost nothing we have is processed, though I can't make my own olive oil, for example. So there are items I have to buy.